# jsTree renaming not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstree

i'm using jstree with the crrm and the json_data plugin. When I try to call the rename function on a node a get an error  obj.trigger is not a function.

my code:

```
    //definiton of tree
    $('selector').jstree({
      //config for tree themes plugin
      'themes' : {
        'theme' : 'classic',
        'dots' : true,
        'icons' : true
      },
      //config for tree json_data plugin
      json_data : {
        ajax : {
          url: '?',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          beforeSend: function( xhr, s ){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/x-json");

          },
          context: this,
          data: $.proxy(this,'_generateTreeJSONData'),
          success: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeLoad'),
          error: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeError')
        }
      },
      //config for tree drag and drop plugin
      dnd:{
        drop_finish: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeDropFinish'),
        drag_finish: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeDragFinish'),
        drop_check: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeDropCheck'),
        drag_check: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeDragCheck'),
        drop_target: false,
        drag_target: false
      },
      //config for tree creating renaming removing moving (crrm) plugin
      crrm:{
         move:{
          check_move: $.proxy(this,'_onTreeMoveCheck')
        }
      },
      plugins : ['themes','json_data','ui','dnd','crrm','contextmenu']
    });

    //conect to click of tree node
    $(".ep-acb-tree a").live("click", $.proxy(this,'_onClickTreeNode'));

    _onClickTreeNode: function(evt){
      $('selector').jstree('rename',evt.currentTarget);
    },
```

This is only a part of my code but drag and drop and everything else is working fine.

Thanks for your help.
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to the `rename_node` like so:

```
.bind("rename_node.jstree", function (node, ref) {
// Your code goes here....
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but my problem is that i can not open the edit mode.
Your solution will bind to the event which is triggered after the rename was done, i guess.
I although tried the contextmenu plugin and when I click rename in the menu I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but have you tried substituting "rename_node" for "rename" in your code? So, instead of $('selector').jstree('rename', ...), try $('selector').jstree('rename_node', ...);